# Radical extension and discriminant of cubic

Tags: galois-theory

Given an irreducible cubic $f = x^3 + px + q$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ I'm trying to show that, for $\alpha$ a root of $f$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a radical extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $-\Delta/3$ is a square.

My ideas so far are that if it is a radical extension then $\alpha^n \in \mathbb{Q}$ for some $n$ and we must have $n \ge 3$ because $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. I also know that the Galois group of $f$ is either $A_3$ or $S_3$ depending on whether $\Delta$ is a square or not.

I'd also like to use the fact that $K(\alpha)$ is a radical extension iff it's Galois group is solvable but how does the condition on the discriminant tell us that this is a Galois extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is a radical extension then it is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]a)$ for some rational $a$, and its Galois closure is obtained by adjoining a third root of unity, so it has to be $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]a, \sqrt{-3})$.

Since in an $S_3$ extension the only quadratic subfield is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt \Delta)$, we must have $\Bbb Q(\sqrt \Delta) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt {-3})$ and so $-3\Delta$ has to be a square.

Conversely, suppose $-3\Delta$ is a square. I could just tell you to apply Cardan's formula but this is no fun.

Let $\beta,\gamma$ be the other two roots.

Then $(\alpha + \zeta_3 \beta + \zeta_3^2 \gamma)^3 = ((\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3)-\frac 32(\alpha^2\beta + \alpha\beta^2+\alpha^2\gamma+\alpha\gamma^2+\beta^2\gamma+\beta\gamma^2) + 6\alpha\beta\gamma) + \frac32 \sqrt{-3}(\beta-\alpha)(\gamma-\beta)(\alpha-\gamma)$

The first half is symmetric so is expressible in terms of the coefficients and is rational.
The second half is $\frac 32 \sqrt{-3 \Delta}$ which is also rational, so $(\alpha + \zeta_3 \beta + \zeta_3^2 \gamma)^3 = b \in \Bbb Q$.

Moreover $(\alpha + \zeta_3 \beta + \zeta_3^2 \gamma)(\alpha + \zeta_3^2 \beta + \zeta_3 \gamma) = \alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2 - \alpha\beta-\beta\gamma-\gamma\alpha \in \Bbb Q$, and $\alpha+\beta+\gamma \in \Bbb Q$, and so $\Bbb Q(\alpha) = \Bbb Q(\alpha+\beta+\gamma,\alpha+\zeta_3\beta+\zeta_3^2\gamma,\alpha+\zeta_3^2\beta+\zeta_3\gamma) = \Bbb Q(\alpha+\zeta_3\beta+\zeta_3^2\gamma) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]b)$ for the right choice of cube root.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your first line how did you deduce that $n=3$? I can only see that $n \ge 3$?

Comment: because $3 = [\Bbb Q(\alpha) : \Bbb Q]$ and usually $n = [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]a) : \Bbb Q]$

Comment: But if $\alpha$ satisfies $f(x) = x^n - a$ what if $f$ is not irreducible? E.g. $\alpha$ might satisfy something like $f(x) = x^5 - a$ but $f$ has the original polynomial as a factor?

Comment: Also reading on in your answer a bit, how do we know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ is a quadratic extension? What is $\Delta$ is a square?

Comment: if $\Delta$ is a square there is no quadratic subfield (either the extension is cyclic or it is trivial), so it can't contain $\sqrt{-3}$

Comment: I'm just coming back to this question after some time - I'm still struggling with the very first part - could you possibly elaborate on why it must be that $n=3$?

Comment: In particular, if $K(\alpha)$ is a radical extension then $a = \alpha^q \in K$ for some q - i.e. $\alpha$ satisfies $g(x) = x^q - a$ but now that polynomial cannot be irreducible since then it must be equal to $f$ which is not the case?

Comment: @mercio i know this question is from a long time ago, but could you explain why we need to attach $\sqrt{-3}$ to get a Galois closure?

Comment: because the cube roots of $1$ are $1$ and $\frac 12(-1 \pm \sqrt{-3})$

Comment: @Wooster probably completely useless to you now, but I think $n=3$ because, if $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_k) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the radical extension (i.e. for each $i$ there exists some $n_i$ such that $\alpha_i ^ {n_i} \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_{i-1})$), then by the tower law we have $3 = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(..., \alpha_k):\mathbb{Q}(..., \alpha_{k-1})]...[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1):\mathbb{Q}]$, so since $3$ is prime, all but one of these factors must be $1$, and the other must be $3$, meaning that the radical extension takes only "one step".